# RegEx - Extract words that contains a substring, from a comma seperated string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Using **Javascript** / **jQuery**, I have the following string;

```
MasterString = "typography,caret,car,card,align,shopping-cart,adjust,allineate";
```

What's the best **RegEx** for extracting all the words that contains e.g. "**car**", so I have the following string left;

```
ResultString = "caret,car,card,shopping-cart";
```

And is it also possible to extract only the first word, that contains "**car**"?

```
ResultString = "caret";
```

*I am writing a simple search-routine, which matches the query (**car**) against a **comma seperated list** and I want to show the first result as the outcome for the query.*

---

**UPDATE**

I tried the simple RegEx mentioned in the answer below;

```
[^,]*car[^,]*
```

It works perfect, see this (test-)image - **https://i.stack.imgur.com/q22is.png**

The query is "**car**" and all icons tagged with a word that contains at least "**car**" are made visible in the search-results.

The only problem is that the search-string "**car**" is always different (depends on user input in the search-form). So how can I enter a variable match-string in the RegEx above?

Something like this;

```
[^,]*%QUERY-FROM-SEARCHFIELD%[^,]*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match only the strings `caret,car,card,shopping-cart`,

```
[^,]*car[^,]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qH7wQ9/2)

```
> var masterString = "typography,caret,car,card,align,shopping-cart,adjust,allineate";
undefined
> masterString.match(/[^,]*car[^,]*/g);
[ 'caret',
  'car',
  'card',
  'shopping-cart' ]
```

To match the first word which contains the string `car`, you need to remove the global flag from the pattern.

```
> masterString.match(/[^,]*car[^,]*/);
[ 'caret',
  index: 11,
  input: 'typography,caret,car,card,align,shopping-cart,adjust,allineate' ]
```

Now convert the array into a string delimited by comma and stored it into a variable.

```
> var resultString = masterString.match(/[^,]*car[^,]*/g).join(",");
undefined
> resultString
'caret,car,card,shopping-cart'
```

Comment: Since the source is a comma-separated string, is the word boundary token really necessary?

Comment: This answer is my favorite, because all the other routines I use (for this project) are RegEx-based as well. Final question; how can I replace "car" in "masterString.match(/[^,]*car[^,]*/)" with a variable query-string?

Comment: like this `masterString.replace(/[^,]*car[^,]*/g, "foo");` ?

Comment: Unfortunately the 'replace' does not work for my case. This works perfect; resultString = masterString.match(/[^,]*car[^,]*/); But the string "car" must be a variable... I think I must parse it to RegExp or something, but can't figure out how...

Comment: Ask it as a different question and don't forget to put a link to this question.

Comment: Thanks - I created another question, regarding this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095765/regex-javascript-match-with-a-variable-keyword

Answer (score 1):

You can do so without regex:

1. Split the string to an array:

   ```
   var tempArray = MasterString.split( ',' );
   ```
2. Filter the array for values which contain the word `car` in it:

   ```
   tempArray = tempArray.filter(function (x) {
       if (x.contains('car')) return x;
   });
   ```
3. Join the resulting array back:

   ```
   ResultString = tempArray.join( ',' );
   ```

---

```
MasterString = "typography,caret,car,card,align,shopping-cart,adjust,allineate";
var tempArray = MasterString.split( ',' );
tempArray = tempArray.filter(function (x) {
    if (x.contains('car')) return x;
});
ResultString = tempArray.join( ',' );
```

---

To get the first result, simply access the 0th element of `tempArray`:

```
var x = tempArray[0];
```