# RegEx - JavaScript .match() with a variable keyword

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

I have a string with keywords, separated by comma's.

Now I also have a nice **RegEx**, *to filter out all the keywords in that string, that matches a queried-string*.

Check out this initial question - [RegEx - Extract words that contains a substring, from a comma seperated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094811/regex-extract-words-that-contains-a-substring-from-a-comma-seperated-string)

The example below works fine; it has a masterString, and a resultString. That last one only contains the keywords that has at least the word "**car**" in it.

```
masterString = "typography,caret,car,align,shopping-cart,adjust,card";
resultString = masterString.match(/[^,]*car[^,]*/g);
console.log(resultString);
```

Result from the code above;

```
"caret", "car", "shopping-cart", "card"
```

But how can I use the RegEx, with a variable matching-word (the word "**car**" in this example static and not variable).

I think it has to do something with a RegExp - but I can't figure out...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Rather than define a new RexExp with a string where you have to replace `|QUERY|` with something, why not just do string concatenation? That's how the RegExp object was meant to be used.

Comment: Thx - I added another solution (#2) which does the job, as you said!

Comment: @ElBandito try typing something like `he(]o` in your search box :)

Comment: @LUCAS - yeah :) But I also cleaned up the query, after submitting and before validating... See the code I used for that overhere... http://i.imgur.com/zC0NzRd.jpg In my case it's safe to use this solution, because it's used in an app, with little user-control (I control all the codes and there behaviour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one?, you only need to replace \ \ with String , and it works for me. it can find whether your string has "car", not other similar word

```
 var query  = 'car';
 var string = "car,bike,carrot,plane,card";
 var strRegEx = '[^,]*'+query+'[,$]*'; 
 string.match(strRegEx);
```

Comment: I picked this one as the answer, because it comes closest to the one I figured out myself (see Update 2). But the other solution on this page is very good as well; They both do their job - thx!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general solution for use with regexes:

```
var query = "anything";    

// Escape the metacharacters that may be found in the query
// sadly, JS lacks a built-in regex escape function
query = query.replace(/[-\\()\[\]{}^$*+.?|]/g, '\\$&');

var regex = new RegExp("someRegexA" + query + "someRegexB", "g");
```

As long as `someRegexA` and `someRegexB` form a valid regex with a literal in-between, the `regex` variable will always hold a valid regex.

But, in your particular case, I'd simply do this:

```
var query = "car";
var items = masterString.split(",");
query = query.toLowerCase();
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    if (items[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(query) >= 0) {
        console.log(items[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> <sup><sub>Answer provided by OP and removed from inside the question</sub></sup>

I figured out this quick-and-maybe-very-dirty solution...

```
var query  = 'car';
var string = "car,bike,carrot,plane,card";
var regex  = new RegExp("[^,]*|QUERY|[^,]*".replace('|QUERY|',query),'ig');
string.match(regex);
```

This code outputs the following, not sure if it is good crafted, 'though..

```
"car", "carrot", "card"
```

**But** ended figuring out another, much simpler solution;

```
var query  = "car";
var string = "car,bike,carrot,plane,card";
string.match(new RegExp("[^,]*"+query+"[^,]*",'ig'));
```

This code outputs the string below;

```
["car", "carrot", "card"]
```

---

My app-search-engine now works perfect :)

[image]